# PHP strip img tags from html, returning the html and the images in an array

Tags: php, html

I need to write a function that takes some HTML, strips out the img tags and returns the html (sans images). However, I also need to retain the imgs (in an array) so I can output them to the page separately.

I barely know any php so what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to familiarize yourself with the [DOMDocument class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).  The best way to do this is parse out the HTML using `DOMDocument`, and locate all the `<img>` tags using `getElementsByTagName('img')`.  If it's the images' `src` attributes you're after, DOMDocument can return those and store in an array.

```
// HTML already parsed into $dom
$imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
$img_src = array();

// Array of nodes to remove.
$to_remove = array();

foreach ($imgs as $img) {
  // Store the img src
  $img_src[] = $img->getAttribute('src');

  // Delete the node (I think this works)
  $to_remove[] = $img;
}

// Then remove all the nodes slated for deletion:
foreach ($to_remove as $node) {
  $dom->removeChild($img);
}
```

Comment: That's pretty interesting stuff, I've bookmarked it for future reading. The HTML I'm working with is returned by a function, not sure if it would work for that?

Comment: @dr_tchock `DOMDocument::loadHTML()` will load HTML from a string rather than a file, and may work for you if your function returns a string. http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php

Comment: You should not remove items from an array while you are iterating over that array inside the loop

Comment: @lovesh Indeed not.  I edited this old post with the correct behavior, storing them onto a separated array for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$pattern = '/<img[^>]*src="([^"]*)[^>]*>/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $data, $matches);

// image src array
$images = $matches[1];

// no images
$html = preg_replace($pattern, '', $data);
?>
```